# Rearranging Panes in Chrome Dev Panel

Tags: google-chrome, browser, google-chrome-devtools

When Chrome's dev panel is placed on either side of the screen and is not too wide, this is how the panel looks:

[image: Narrow]

I particularly like how the Styles pane and the Computed pane are side by side. For example, this makes checking if my CSS is correctly applied very easy.

However, sometimes I wish to have a wide dev panel to house more content. The problem is, when I drag the dev panel any bit wider, this happens:

[image]

As you can see, the Styles and Computed panes become two tabs on the same pane, and I often find myself switching back and forth - an annoying inconvenience in short.

### So my question is simply

Is there any way to rearrange those panels manually?

Or alternatively, can I somehow convince Chrome to keep using the "narrow layout" regardless of dev panel width?

### Using

Chrome 79

Windows 10 Pro N 1909 & CentOS 7 1908

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Accidentally found the solution today.

In Chrome 83 (not sure about backward support), `Dev Panel`>`Settings`>`Preferences`>`Panel Layout := Horizontal`.

[image: Screenshot]

This forces the dev panel to adopt the first type of layout regardless of its width.